# Plotting using arange to define variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have recently started learning Python.

I have learnt that in order to define the independent variable (z in the example below), you can write using numpy.linspace():

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as pp
import numpy as np
from math import pi

#z=np.linspace(1,-1) z definition works
z=np.arange(1,-1) #z definition does not work
w=z

pp.plot(z,w)
pp.xlabel("Input")
pp.ylabel("Output")
pp.title("Function")
pp.show()
print(z,w)
```

However, if we define z using np.arange (see commented line, it seems impossible to get the plot displayed (no graph appears).
If I want to use the latter defintition for the independent variable, can I still plot the other variable or am I forced to use the linspace definition?
Thanks

Comment: That's because `np.arange(1, -1)` tries to go from 1 to -1 with a (default) step of 1. If you check the value of `z` made from this statement, it should be an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.linspace(1, -1)` creates an array of numbers that starts with `1` and ends with `-1`. Default there are 50 steps taken, so each step has a length of `-2/49`. Usually, the number of steps is given explicitly, for example `np.linspace(1, -1, 200)`. Standard, the start value is chosen to be smaller than the stop value, but both ways work.

`np.arange(1, -1)` creates an array starting from 1, adding a step (default is 1), and ends when the value is larger or equal to the stop value. So, in this case it just stops immediately, creating an empty array. `np.arange(1, -1, -1)` would take steps of -1, and create an array `[1, 0]`, stopping just before `-1`.

Numpy's magic starts when these arrays are used in expressions as if they were single variables. This is called [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Here is an example plot that shows the working of `np.linspace`. `w` is only calculated for the 50 given values of `z`. Note that although `z` is created from `1` to `-1`, the default plot shows the positive side at the right. Also note that the standard way to import matplotlib is as `plt`, which makes it easier for other people to follow the code.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

z = np.linspace(1, -1)
w = np.sin(z * np.pi)
plt.plot(z, w, '-bo')
plt.xlabel('$z$')
plt.ylabel(r'$w = \sin(z * pi)$')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]